# Por qué si cambio el orden de una declaración de `String` me marca error?

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, matemáticas, pilas

Esta declaración de `String op = tokens.next();` tengo que hacerla dentro del ciclo `while`
, si la pongo fuera del ciclo, i.e. `String op=null; while{...op=tokens.next();...}` me marca un error que dice: `The assigned value is never used`, pero es una contradicción porque sí lo uso dentro del `while`.

Luego en otras ocasiones exige que la declaracion este fuera del ciclo, como por ejemplo en los ciclos`for`.

```
public static int postfixEvaluate(String exp) {
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer> ();
    Scanner tokens = new Scanner(exp);
    //String op =null;
    while (tokens.hasNext()) {
        if (tokens.hasNextInt()) 
            s.push(tokens.nextInt());
         else {
            int num2 = s.pop();
            int num1 = s.pop();
            String op = tokens.next();

            if (op.equals("+")) 
                s.push(num1 + num2);
            else {
                                if (op.equals("-")) 
                s.push(num1 - num2);
                                else{
                                    if (op.equals("*")) 
                s.push(num1 * num2);
            else 
                s.push(num1 / num2);



        }
    }}}
    return s.pop();

    }}
```

Comment: ¿Qué IDE usas, Netbeans, Eclipse...? ¿Es un **error** lo que te marca o una **advertencia** (warning)?

Comment: @A.Cedano creo que es un warning, porque el programa si compila, pero me marca un tipo error diciendo: `The assigned...`

Comment: Eso sospechaba que era una advertencia, estaba probando en mi Netbeans y pasa lo mismo, pero era una advertencia. De ser un error no compilaría.Te hice la pregunta sobre el IDE que usas porque he leído sobre un bug en Netbeans y quizá también en Eclipse sobre este asunto. Hice pruebas de código declarando la variable y usándola, y también usando el valor de la variable (asignándoselo a otra) y marca el mismo warning. Puede que sea un bug.

Comment: aah si alomejor, uso netbeans @A.Cedano

Comment: Te recomiendo que las variables las inicialices a su valor mas simple
int a =0;
String cadena="";
etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### I. Ni es un error ni es cosa del compilador

En realidad no se trata de un error, sino de una advertencia (warning), pero no del compilador, sino que es una funcionalidad del IDE, en este caso Netbeans (como has confirmado en comentarios).

Esta funcionalidad se llama [*Unused Assignment*](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB71#Hints) (asignación no usada), y fue introducida en NetBeans 7.1:

> ***Asignación no utilizada***
>
> Se introdujo un nuevo par de consejos, *asignación no utilizada* y *rama muerta*. La *asignación no utilizada* encuentra valores que se calculan y asignan a una variable,
>   pero nunca se utilizan al leer la variable. La pista de *rama muerta*
>   busca bifurcaciones de código que nunca se pueden ejecutar.

Puedes ver al respecto este artículo de JavaWorld: [NetBeans 7.1's Unused Assignment and Dead Branch Hints](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2074514/core-java/netbeans-7-1-s-unused-assignment-and-dead-branch-hints.html)

Lo que ocurre es lo que dice @Flowen en su respuesta: **asignas un valor que nunca usas**, de modo que en lenguaje coloquial el IDE te dice: *¿Para qué me asignas un valor si no lo vas a usar*?

Veamos dos fragmentos de código:

#### Fragmento 1:

El IDE no te reclamará nada, porque asignas el valor y lo usas:

```
String op=null;
for(int i=10; i>1; i--)
{
    System.out.println("Variable inicial: "+op);
}
```

#### Fragmento 2:

El IDE te reclamará, porque asignas el valor y no lo usas:

```
String op=null;
for(int i=10; i>1; i--)
{
    // System.out.println("Variable inicial: "+op);
}
```

¿Y si lo hago así me reclama también? Aquí si uso `op` ¿no?

```
String op=null;
for(int i=10; i>1; i--)
{
    op="a";
    System.out.println("Variable inicial: "+op);

}
```

También te reclama, porque asignaste `null` para nada (lo que se imprime es el valor de `op` cambiado al valor `a`.

---

### II. Es una funcionalidad cargada de bugs

Como ya se ha dicho en **I**, se trata de una funcionalidad del IDE, la cual está cargada de bugs. Para comprobarlo, sólo tienes que hacer esta búsqueda en google: `site:netbeans.org unused assignment` te mostrará todo sobre esta funcionalidad en netbeans.org, no por casualidad la mayor parte de los resultados de búsqueda son reportes de bugs.

---

### III. ¿Qué hago?

La lección que quiere darnos *Unused assignement* es que no declares nada con valores que no vayas a usar.

Si no vas a usar el `null` no tiene ninguna utilidad declarar tu variable así:

```
String op=null;
```

Declárala así:

```
String op; //=null;
```

Y asígnale el valor sólo si lo vas a usar:

```
for(int i=10; i>1; i--)
{
    op="a";
    System.out.println("Variable: "+op);
}
```

Pero si haces esto:

```
for(int i=10; i>1; i--)
{
    op="a";
    System.out.println("Variable: "+op);
    op="b";
}
```

En el `op="b"` tendrás la misma advertencia: *Unused assignement*. ¿Por qué?  El IDE no es tan tonto como lo pintan. Aunque pase por el bucle, esa `op=b` nunca se usará.

La advertencia se quitaría si hicieras esto:

```
for(int i=10; i>1; i--)
{
    op="a";
    System.out.println("Variable inicial: "+op);
    op="b";
    System.out.println("Variable cambiada: "+op);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> The assigned value is never used

Lo que te indica es que el valor `null` que le has asignado, no se utiliza nunca. Y es cierto, ya que lo reemplazas por `tokens.next();` dentro del `while`.

Es decir, te habla del `valor` de la variable, no de la variable `op` en sí.

Answer (score 2):

`The assigned value is never used` significa que es inútil asignar un valor a esa variable `op` al momento de declararla, ya que la siguiente expresión que hace referencia a `op` es precisamente una asignación de un nuevo valor con `op = tokens.next();`

Si deseas *declarar* la variable `op` fuera del lazo `while`, puedes hacerlo sin asignarle valores, así:

```
String op;
```

y al momento de *asignarla* dentro del lazo, utilizas:

```
op = tokens.next();
```

Comment: no, no es inutil.De hecho si la declaro `null` fuera del `while` el programa termina mal, porque nunca leera `op = tokens.next();` (no se porque) y `op` siempre se mantiene con el mismo valor: `null`

Comment: @Michelle no va a importar, ya que solo estás asignando un valor a la variable `op`, a la cual enseguida se le asignará un nuevo valor dentro del lazo `while`.
El error que comentas puede deberse a que al momento de asignación estés utilizando `String op = tokens.next();` en vez de `op = tokens.next();`

Answer (score 1):

> pero es una contradicción porque sí lo uso dentro del **while**

Utilizas la variable `op` **siempre y cuando se ejecute el `else`** y para el analizador, tanto el `if` como el `else` tienen las mismas probabilidades de ejecutarse por lo que te advierte que si se ejecuta el `if`, la variable `op` no esta siendo utilizada. Por lo que te recomienda declarar la variable en el `else`.

Si eliminas la asignación inicial la advertencia se ira:

```
String op;      
while (tokens.hasNext()) 
{
```

O si por ejemplo imprimes el valor del `op` en el `if`, la advertencia también desaparecerá:

```
String op = null;      
while (tokens.hasNext()) 
{

    if (tokens.hasNextInt()) 
    {
        System.out.println(op);
        s.push(tokens.nextInt());
    }
    else {
//...
```

Obviamente no utilizas la variable `op` en el branch `if` lo que indica que el analizador no es lo suficientemente inteligente como para ignorar la advertencia.