# error Un used assignement en netbean

Tags: java, netbeans-12

Escribo para que por favor me ayuden a aclarar la siguiente situación: En Netbeans 12.0 siempre me aparece el error Un used assignment cuando realizo el código adjunto. Me aparece ese error en `String nombre, int clave int antiguedad`. Cuando corro el código a travéz de la consola de cmd me dá como debe ser pero en Netbeans no. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Sistema {
    public static void main(String args[]){
            
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String nombre ="";
        int clave =0;
        int antiguedad =0;
        System.out.println("*****************************************************");
        System.out.println("Bienvenido al sistema vacacional de Coca-Cola Company");
        System.out.println("*****************************************************");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Cual es el nombre del trabajador?: ");
        nombre=entrada.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Cuanto tiempo de servicio tiene el trabajador?: ");
        antiguedad=entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Cual es la clave del departamento del trabajador?: ");
        clave=entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        if (clave==1){
        if (antiguedad==1){
          System.out.println("El trabajador"+nombre+"tiene derecho a 6 días de vacaciones");
          
        }else if(antiguedad>=2 && antiguedad<=6){
        System.out.println("El trabajador"+nombre+"tiene derecho a 14 días de vacaciones");
        }else if(antiguedad>=7){
        System.out.println("El trabajador"+nombre+"tiene derecho a 20 días de vacaciones");
        
        }else if(clave==2){
         if (antiguedad==1){
          System.out.println("El trabajador"+nombre+"tiene derecho a 7 días de vacaciones");
          
        }else if(antiguedad>=2 && antiguedad<=6){
        System.out.println("El trabajador"+nombre+"tiene derecho a 15 días de vacaciones");
        }else if(antiguedad>=7){
        System.out.println("El trabajador"+nombre+"tiene derecho a 22 días de vacaciones");
        }
        }else if(clave==3){
         if (antiguedad==1){
          System.out.println("El trabajador"+nombre+"tiene derecho a 10 días de vacaciones");
          
        }else if(antiguedad>=2 && antiguedad<=6){
        System.out.println("El trabajador"+nombre+"tiene derecho a 20 días de vacaciones");
        }else if(antiguedad>=7){
        System.out.println("El trabajador"+nombre+"tiene derecho a 30 días de vacaciones");
        }
        }else{
        System.out.println("Error, la clave del departamento es incorrecta");
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: esto responde a tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103009/por-qu%C3%A9-si-cambio-el-orden-de-una-declaraci%C3%B3n-de-string-me-marca-error/103012

Comment: ¿Estás seguro/a de que es un error y no una _advertencia_?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Por qué si cambio el orden de una declaración de \`String\` me marca error?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/103009/por-qu%c3%a9-si-cambio-el-orden-de-una-declaraci%c3%b3n-de-string-me-marca-error)

Comment: Está explicado en la respuesta a la pregunta de la cual la tuya sería un duplicado. El problema es que tú asignas un valor vacío para `nombre` por ejemplo, y **ese valor vacío nunca lo usas**, porque luego cambias el valor de la variable. Dos soluciones son posibles: 1. Declarar la variable así: `String nombre;` o bien 2. Declarar la variable y asignarle el valor al mismo tiempo: `String nombre=entrada.nextLine();`

Comment: La solución 1 aplicaría cuando `nombre` esté destinada a cambiar de valor **más de una vez** y si necesitas usarla en diferentes contextos, por ejemplo, dentro de bloques o métodos distintos (la declaras fuera de los bloques específicos para poder usarla donde la necesites). La solución 2 aplicaría cuando `nombre` esté destinada a adquirir un valor **una sola vez** o si cambia de valor únicamente dentro del bloque en que la declaras y no fuera de él. Sea como sea, **no le asignes valores que NUNCA usarás**, porque el Netbeans te lanzará una advertencia si lo haces.